# How does Rcpp check Vector/Matrix boundaries?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp

I am experimenting with Rcpp to see how boundary checking works:

```
> cppFunction ('double fun(){NumericVector v(5); return v[-10];}', rebuild=T)
> fun()
[1] 1.782105e-316
> cppFunction ('double fun(){NumericVector v(5); return v[5];}', rebuild=T)
> fun()
[1] 5.323385e-316

> cppFunction ('NumericVector fun(){NumericMatrix v(5, 5); return v(6,_);}', rebuild=T)
> fun()
Error: index out of bounds
> cppFunction ('double fun(){NumericMatrix v(5, 5); return v(6,1);}', rebuild=T)
> fun()
[1] 0
```

I can't really understand how it is (not) working. I was expecting 'index out of bounds' error for all 4 of them. What should I do to make it always work for both vectors and matrices? Here are some verbose output from compilation:

```
Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_81484_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/RtmprtDNus/sourcecpp_5b065bfe9a2d/sourceCpp_20261.so')

fun <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function() {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_81484_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_81484_fun')

rm(`.sourceCpp_81484_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/RtmprtDNus/sourcecpp_5b065bfe9a2d

/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_20261.so' --preclean 'file5b0652a2d520.cpp' 
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include" -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c file5b0652a2d520.cpp -o file5b0652a2d520.o
g++ -shared -o sourceCpp_20261.so file5b0652a2d520.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

Do I need to modify -O3 or -DNDEBUG arguments?

Comment: Short version: Rcpp doesn't do bounds checking. If you index out of bounds, you get garbage.

Comment: @KevinUshey so, what about "Error: index out of bounds"?

Comment: Good point. I guess what I should have said is, 'bounds checking is implemented inconsistently'. :) (Ie, it's Rcpp, not your system / compiler flags or anything, I believe)

I think this is a bug in Rcpp, or at least something worth looking into.

Comment: FWIW Armadillo vector *does* bounds checking by default, but also offer an alternate that omits the check. The warning is clear: "Not recommend for use unless your code has been thoroughly debugged."

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it would be awesome to disable/enable it for Rcpp vector/matrix types, as well.

Comment: @gkcn "Wishing alone does not make it so." That requires changes throughout the Vector class(es). Not a small job, but noted.  Kevin had also already opened a Github ticket for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two first examples, there are no bounds checks. Bounds checks are expensive. What you get is undefined behavior. Symptoms in this case are you get garbage, but you could also get a segfault.

Your third example use the `_` placeholder to extract a row. Upon construction of the `MatrixRow` object, which represents the concept of the row, an exception is thrown because there is no such row. You can reason that it is worth here to do a bounds check since it checks "the whole row".

Your last example looks like a bug. probably in [Vector::offset](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L240)

Comment: As a sidenote, in Rcpp11, there are no bounds checks on the 4th example, so you'd get undefined behavior. Sometimes performance relies on the user to do the right thing.

Comment: Not sure if having bounds checks disabled by default is the right thing to do. In practice, yes, they do slow things down by about 10%-20%, but this needs to be put into the greater context of development and debugging time. If having bounds checks enabled by default allows quicker development, there is considerable time saved. Once the user is happy their code works correctly, they can turn off the bounds checks.

Comment: Sure. I guess you can negociate that with the Rcpp team. For Rcpp11, we are starting to think about how to give this sort of switch. https://github.com/Rcpp11/Rcpp11/issues/141 The true way to achieve development zen however is through unit testing. bounds checks on vectors is one of many things.

Comment: So Rcpp and Rcpp11 are two separate packages? This is confusing: doesn't Rcpp also handle C++11?  Which one does bounds checking, and which doesn't?

Comment: Sure, you can use C++11 with Rcpp. Now if you want an implementation of the codebase that fully understands and leverage C++11. You want Rcpp11.

Comment: Rcpp and Rcpp11 are indeed two different packages, maintained by two different people. We have different takes on how to maintain the code base. We don't agree. I choosed to split and maintain Rcpp11, which is more oriented towards what I consider to be the future of interfacing R and C++.